# Looking for better way to pass range for my function sumBlack()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would love to be able use my script in Google sheet with just =sumBlack(C4:14)

currently my script ** see below ** works in Google sheet with =sumBlack(3,4,14)
3 for column, 4 and 14 are the row start and end

here's my code... pleased that it works though
it sums only cells that have the fontColor of black

---

```
function sumBlack(column, rowst, rowend) {
  result = 0;
  for(row = rowst;row <= rowend;row++){
    var txtColor = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getCell(row, column).getFontColor();
    if(txtColor == "#000000"){
       result = result + SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getCell(row, column).getValue();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to sum the values of cells, when the font color is `#000000` as hex.
- You want to achieve this using the custom function.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, in order to give the a1Notation to the custom function, how about using `=sumBlack("C4:14")` instead of `=sumBlack(C4:14)`? Because when `=sumBlack(C4:14)` is used, the values of cells "C4:14" is given as 2 dimensional array. By this, the range cannot be known.
- In this modification, `getFontColors()` and `getValues() are used instead of` getFontColor()`and`getValue(), respectively. By this, I think that the process cost will be able to be reduced.

When you can permit this suggestion, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

When you use this script, please put `=sumBlack("C4:14")` to a cell. In this case, please don't forget to enclose the a1Notation with `"`.

```
function sumBlack(a1Notation) {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(a1Notation);
  const fontColors = range.getFontColors();
  const values = range.getValues();
  const result = fontColors.reduce((n, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (c == "#000000") n += Number(values[i][j]);
    });
    return n;
  }, 0);
  return result;
}
```

- If you want to give the sheet name like `=sumBlack("Sheet1!C4:14")`, please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(a1Notation);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(a1Notation);
    ```
- In above modified script, when `=sumBlack("C4:14")` is put and the cell value of "C4:14" is changed, no recalculation occurs. If you want to recalculate for this situation, please add the following script. The following script is automatically run when the cells in the active sheet are edited, and the formula of `=sumBlack()` is recalculated.

  ```
    function onEdit(e) {
      const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.createTextFinder("=sumBlack").matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith("###sumBlack");
      sheet.createTextFinder("###sumBlack").matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith("=sumBlack");
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getFontColors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolors)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)